# Unit test a function in a service without actually calling the function

Tags: unit-testing, spock

I have a basic unit test that builds an object and passes it to a service method. That method then checks the image Type and calls the `convertToDicomService.async(uploadedFile)` function. I want my unit test to only test if that block of code is working and not call the other function.

```
def "sync uploaded file"() {
    given:
    def  eventRouterService = Mock(EventRouterService)
    UploadedFile uploadedFile = UploadedFile.build()
    uploadedFile.uploadedFileType = UploadedFileType.DICOM

    when:
    service.handlePossiblyReadyToSend(uploadedFile)

    then:
    1 * eventRouterService.handleFileReadyToSend(uploadedFile)
}
```

and this is the service method

```
def handlePossiblyReadyToSend(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
    log.trace("Determining if file is READY_TO_SEND: $uploadedFile")
    switch (uploadedFile.uploadedFileType) {
        case UploadedFileType.JPEG:
            convertToDicomService.async(uploadedFile)
            break
        case UploadedFileType.DICOM:
            handleFileReadyToSend(uploadedFile)
            break
        default:
            // Bad news bears: We don't know this file type! (should not happen, since it's an enum)
            log.error("Impossible uploaded file type found: $uploadedFile")
            break
    }
}
```

Also, I'm somewhat new to unit testing and open to any related suggestions

Comment: First, refer spockframework docs on how to mock objects. Second, once you are able to mock the service class it should be easy to mock the method `async` the way you want it to behave. Third, assign that mocked service class object to your main service under test.

Comment: I've changed my test and the then block fails to pass (0 invocations). I was using code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/Interactions as a reference. Am I on the right track?

Comment: You should always be referring to [spockframework's docs](http://spock-framework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html). code.google docs are pretty old but you can grasp few things about a spec from there as well. But positively look at the one I mentioned.

Comment: Have you successfully mocked `convertToDicomService`? If so, it is just a matter of registering the interactions in Spock. If not, you must find a way to inject the mock into your class. Sometimes, if I'm not sure what is happening, I create a breakpoint where the mock is about to be used and check in the debugger whether the mock is used or the actual class is used.